# JQuery's load() and delay() functions not working

Tags: jquery, load, delay

I'm trying to use jquery to set some default text in a form input.  The text will be dynamic and so I can't just set this in the html.  I want the jquery to wait for the form to load.

The delay function sets the text, but doesn't delay at all.  It's instant.

Nothing in the load function seems to execute.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Testinput</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="testinput.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
  <input size="20" name="thing" />
  <input type="image" src="" name="submit" value="go" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $input = $('input[name="thing"]');
$input.val("");

var query = "orange";

//$input.delay(10000).val(query); // No delay!

$input.load(function(){ 
// Nothing happens!!
alert("form loaded");
$input.val(query);
});

});
```

Tried both jquery-1.6.4.min.js and jquery-1.4.min.js to no avail.

---

Edit: 
I can't respond to replies, javascript on stack overflow doesn't seem to be working correctly for me.  I get "Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load".

I've gotten the delay function working using Clive's answer, but is there a way to make jquery wait for a form to have loaded first before running code?

Comment: @shafty: Regarding your edit: You're already doing it...`$(document).ready` will only be run when the DOM is ready, at which point the form will be fully loaded and available in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) relates to queues, not arbitrary functions so you need to use `setTimeout()` instead:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
  var $input = $('input[name="thing"]');
  var query = 'orange';
  $input.val(query);
}, 10000);
```

Also [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is a function to:

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

It won't work for what you're trying to do

Comment: Is there a way to make jquery wait for a form to have loaded first before running code?  The delay function works, but isn't always a practical solution.